# How to add new column to an existing csv file and find age from DOB of that csv file?

Tags: python, csv, opencsv

My CSV file has three columns, the first column names, the second column is DOB(YYYYMM-DD) the third column is salary
looks like this kind of

```
Name,DOB,Salary
Sam,2000-01-05,23000
Tyson,1989-09-11,29000
Lara,2002-11-19,19000
Brian,1990-04-20,21000
Tessa,2000-08-17,15000
```

Problem statement- **Read the file and display the data and find their age in the terminal.**

Therefore, I want to add a new column called 'Age', It'll print their age accordingly.

```
Name,DOB,Salary,Age
Sam,2000-01-05,23000,22
Tyson,1989-09-11,29000,51
Lara,2002-11-19,19000,20
Brian,1990-04-20,21000,32
Tessa,2000-08-17,15000,22
```

I did something like this.

```
import csv
import datetime


def getage(now, dob):
    years = now.year - dob.year
    months = now.month - dob.month
    if now.day < dob.day:
        months -= 1
        while months < 0:
            months += 12
            years -= 1
    return '%sy%smo' % (years, months)


with open('emp_details.csv', 'r') as fin, open('emp_details_out.csv', 'w') as fout:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(fin)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(fout)

    for data in csv_reader:
        today = datetime.date.today()
        DOB = datetime.datetime.strptime(data["DOB"], "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        data["Age"] = getage(today, DOB)
        csv_writer.writerow(data)
```

Where it shows the error below

```
DOB = datetime.datetime.strptime(data["DOB"], "%Y-%m-%d").date()
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I'm new with csv files, That's why i need some help, If This Question looks like inappropriate please consider it. I genuinely need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also recommend using pandas here, credit to @It_is_Chris.

In case you want to know why your code doesn't work, there are few little things you didn't consider.

`csv.reader` returns a list of lists of your data. The first element of this list is a list with the headers. You can't access elements of each row with the header name of the column, instead you need to access them by index.

You could also use `csv.DictReader` and `csv.DictWriter` to solve this. Then you need to add the key value pair of Age for each row (which is a dictionary) with the syntax you used, e.g `row['Age']`

I didn't change anything in your function `getage`.

```
# 1

with open('emp_details.csv', 'r') as fin, open('emp_details_out.csv', 'w') as fout:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(fin)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(fout)
    
    header = next(csv_reader) + ['Age'] # take first row of csv_reader as header and add 'Age'
    csv_writer.writerow(header)
    
    for data in csv_reader:
        # for 1st row, data is a list and looks like this: ['Sam', '2000-01-05', '23000']
        today = datetime.date.today()
        DOB = datetime.datetime.strptime(data[1], "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        data.append(getage(today, DOB))
        csv_writer.writerow(data)

# OR 
# 2

with open('emp_details.csv', 'r') as fin, open('emp_details_out.csv', 'w') as fout:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(fin)
    
    header = csv_reader.fieldnames + ['Age']
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(fout, fieldnames=header)
    csv_writer.writeheader()
    
    for data in csv_reader:
        # for 1st row, data is a dictionary and looks like this: {'Name': 'Sam', 'DOB': '2000-01-05', 'Salary': '23000'}
        today = datetime.date.today()
        DOB = datetime.datetime.strptime(data['DOB'], "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        data['Age'] = getage(today, DOB)
        csv_writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: In 1st one you have written like data[1] and in 2nd you wrote like data['DOB'] why? Can you explain lil bit.
@Rabinzel

Comment: In the 1st one, `data` is a list. list elements only can be accessed by index (that's what your error message is telling you, index must be integer, not a string). Since `Age` is always the 2nd element in that list, we access it by `data[1]`. In the 2nd example I used `csv.DictReader`. Each row is a dictionary, with different key/value pairs for each column. If you try to access the value of a dictionary you need the key `data['DOB']` where `"DOB"` is the key to the 2nd value in that row.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easiest to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime


df = pd.read_csv('some/file/path/file_name.csv')  # read your csv using the file's path
df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'])  # convert date to datetime
df['Age'] = (datetime.datetime.now() - df['DOB']).dt.days // 365  # calculate the age
df.to_csv('/some/file/path/file_name.csv', index=False)  # create a csv file or update existing 

    Name        DOB  Salary  Age
0    Sam 2000-01-05   23000   22
1  Tyson 1989-09-11   29000   33
2   Lara 2002-11-19   19000   19
3  Brian 1990-04-20   21000   32
4  Tessa 2000-08-17   15000   22
```

Comment: Your code is working absolutely fine, Thanks for helping me but can you help me with my code like where is the error which i can't figure it out.

Comment: @Psyfer.Dev check my answer for an explanation.

Comment: @Rabinzel Already checked your answer It works perfect and thanks for clearing my doubts.